# Using JQuery.map() to map two tables with corresponding data as one array

Tags: jquery

I'm scraping information from a website. I am trying to get the following information from the two tables.

PlayerRank PlayerName Prizes

The information in both tables are correlated.

I then need to enter the information for each player into my database.

I'm stuck right now trying to get the information from both tables into 1 array.

I created a JSFiddle to try different things http://jsfiddle.net/drycsLjk/4/

### Table One

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rank</th>

          <th>Prizes</th>

          <th>Additional Prizes</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
          <td>1</td>

          <td>$2.5</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
          <td>2</td>

          <td>$1.5</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
          <td>3</td>

          <td>$1</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
          <td>4</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
          <td>5</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
          <td>6</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
          <td>7</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
          <td>8</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
          <td>9</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
          <td>10</td>

          <td>$0</td>

          <td>N/A</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

### Table Two

```
<table id="ranked_players">
            <thead>
             <tr><th>RANK</th>
             <th>NAME</th>
             <th>CHIPS</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>


                     <tr class="odd">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>shanghai</td>
                <td>20000.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="even">
                <td>2</td>
                <td>SOCRATES</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="odd">
                <td>3</td>
                <td>mollypop</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="even">
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Vegaz</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="odd">
                <td>5</td>
                <td>aRrOwDreWLs</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="even">
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Cheatos</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="odd">
                <td>7</td>
                <td>easypoker</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="even">
                <td>8</td>
                <td>YNVME</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="odd">
                <td>9</td>
                <td>askewbowl</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                     <tr class="even">
                <td>10</td>
                <td>funlv</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
             </tr>
                            </tbody>
         </table>
```

### The JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                var columns = $('#ranked_players thead th').map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                });

                var playerTable = $('#ranked_players tbody tr').map(function(i) {
                  var row = {};
                  $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
                    var rowName = columns[i];
                    row[rowName] = $(this).text();
                  });
                  return row;
                }).get();


                console.log(playerTable);
                var columns = $('#prize_info_container table thead th').map(function() {
                  return $(this).text();
                });
                var prizeTable = $('#prize_info_container table tbody tr').map(function(i) {
                  var row = {};
                  $(this).find('td').each(function(i) {
                    var rowName = columns[i];
                    row[rowName] = $.trim($(this).text());
                  });
                  return row;
                }).get();


                console.log(prizeTable);


            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways you could do this. You could use one `map` and use the index provided as argument to get the other table data to combine with the table you are mapping over....

OR

Use what you have already done and at the end use :

```
var results = $.extend(true, prizeTable, playerTable);
```

**[Demo using $.extend](http://jsfiddle.net/drycsLjk/9/)**

OR

Append the cells from second table to first table then get columns and map the first table

Comment: How do I do this without having a duplicate rank?

Comment: oh yeah..didn't notice that...give me a few minutes

Comment: really simple way is make both headings text lower case when making the `columns` then the same property would exist and wouldn't have to do anything else.. won't end up with 2 properties..just one. That's the way extend works...if property exists it sets first value to what second is

Comment: I'm not sure how to append the cells from the first table to the second. I think I should be able to work with this. Thank you, very much.

Comment: When making the `columns`? Do you mean by adding `.toLowerCase()` under `var columns = `...

Also, does it matter than I have used columns twice?

Comment: no, doesn't matter using twice  ... here's a shorter merge tables version also  http://jsfiddle.net/drycsLjk/8/